# yii assigning foreign key values for auto increment before saving

Tags: sql, yii

In my web application I have three tables namely user,producer_offer,consumer_req. The relationship is such that  the 'id' column of the user table which is a primary key is the foreign key of the  'offered_by' column of producer table ,and 'requested_by' column of 'consumer_req' table.
This is my relation

```
//   user.id=producer_offer.offered_by (it should be the other way)
      producer_offer.offered_by=user.id;
  //  user.id=consumer_req.requested_by(it should be  the other way)
      cpnsumer_req.requested_by=user.id
```

Now I want in such a way that before creating the user record itself based on the user type(producer,consumer) the assignment should be made so that it auto increments. ie, while creating the user itself 
I want like this

```
producer=new ProducerOffer
consumer=new ConsumerReq
if(user->type==producer){
user->id=ProducerOffer.offered_by
}
if(user->type==consumer){
user->id==ConsumerReq.requested_by
}
```

How should I proceed ? I know I can use beforeSave() method but I have already used it for hashing the user password. How should I proceed ,anybody kindly help me with this.Since I am a newbie.

### Structure of my table(producer_offer)

```
--------------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field               | Type             | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+---------------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| id                  | int(4)           | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
| requested_by        | int(11) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL              |                |
| requested_vegetable | int(3)           | NO   | MUL | NULL              |                |
| requested_qty       | decimal(4,2)     | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| requested_date      | timestamp        | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                |
+---------------------+------------------+--
```

Structure of my table consumer_req

```
+---------------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field               | Type             | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+---------------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| id                  | int(4)           | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
| requested_by        | int(11) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL              |                |
| requested_vegetable | int(3)           | NO   | MUL | NULL              |                |
| requested_qty       | decimal(4,2)     | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| requested_date      | timestamp        | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                |
+---------------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
```

user table

```
+--------------+-------------------------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field        | Type                                | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+--------------+-------------------------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| id           | int(11) unsigned                    | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
| user         | varchar(45)                         | NO   | UNI | NULL              |                |
| email        | varchar(60)                         | NO   | UNI | NULL              |                |
| pass         | char(64)                            | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| user_type    | enum('producer','consumer','admin') | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| date_entered | timestamp                           | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                |
| phone_number | varchar(18)                         | NO   | UNI | NULL              |                |
| street       | varchar(30)                         | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| district     | varchar(30)                         | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| state        | varchar(30)                         | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| postal_code  | int(20)                             | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
+--------------+-------------------------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
```

I have put the structures of my table

Comment: "the assignment should be made so that it auto increments". increment what?

Comment: means every time a user of type producer is created the user id should be assigned to offered_by of producer table and every time a user of type consumer is created the user id should be assigned to requested_by of consumer of table

Answer (score 0):

As user_id is a foreign key in other tables so it is necessary that first user exists then the records for `producer` and `consumer`are created. If you create them without creating user first, then it will give refrential integrity constraint violation. 
I assume the other attributes in producer and consumer are nullable so it will not give givee error.
for example in create action of user.

```
    public actionCreate()
    {

            if(isset($_POST['User']))
            {
                $model->attributes=$_POST['User'];
                if($model->save())
                    { if($model->type=='producer'){
    $producer=new ProducerOffer(); 
        $producer->offered_by=$model->id;
           //similar for other attributes of producer
           $producer->save();
    }
    if($model->type=='consumer'){
            $consumer=new ConsumerReq();
            $consumer->requested_by=$model->id;
             //similar for other attributes
               $consumer->save();
       }

    }
  }

}
```

As `requested_by` and `offered_by` should be set in controller so they need not to be on the input form. You need to remove that attribute from your form and remove below mentioned line from your model

```
public function rules()
    {
        return array(
            array('requested_by', 'required'),//remove requested_by from here.
        );
    }
```

**Edit:**
This error is occurring because you are trying to put a string in the int type attribute in database. When you made model then somehow your attribute  `requested_by` was set to string type attribute. so when you try to insert a string in `int` type attribute, this error occurs.
If you look at the model you will see some lines with `@` on the top. these are the attributes of your model. You will see that as

```
* @property string $requested_by
```

So you need to parse the string to int before saving the model.
try

```
$model->offered_by=(int)$_POST['User']['requested_by']
```

As $_POST['User']['requested_by'] will have the current value. and int will convert it to int.

Comment: no actually other attributes are not null , how should I modify it?

Comment: actually you dont need to modify the tables. Rather you should make such flow of app that producerOffer and CustomerReq are not created first. Please show structure of your tables in the question so i can help further.

Comment: just now i added the structures of my table

Comment: Please define some flow of your app because generally user is created first then other entities. You tell which table do you want to be created first? Do you want to create consumer or producer first and then user?

Comment: First the user table is created and then the others

Comment: If that is the case then have you tried above code? Whats the problems you are facing in applying that code?

Comment: the user is created but the other table value foreign keys  are not getting assigned

Comment: or else is there aby way by which I can use beforeSave method in user models? but I have already used that method to hash the password

Comment: CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`AFFM`.`consumer_req`, CONSTRAINT `consumer_req_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`requested_vegetable`) REFERENCES `vegetable` (`id`)). The SQL statement executed was: INSERT INTO `consumer_req` (`requested_vegetable`, `requested_qty`, `requested_date`) VALUES (:yp0, :yp1, :yp2)                                    Thats the error I am getting

Comment: ya I have already removed that ,I am getting this error after I removed that only

Comment: This error may be due to fact that as requested_vegetable is foreign key in consumer_req, it is possible that the value u are trying to insert in this attribute, does not exist in the vegetable table. The value u are trying to put in this attribute, the same value should lie in the vegetable under that column that u are refrencing.

Comment: for example your are putting "3" in the consumer_req. If a record with Id=3 in vegetable does not exist then it will be integrity constraint violation.

Comment: I tried by assigning the same value in vegetables table to the requested_vegetable  of consumer_req,but  I am getting the same error

Comment: what is the type and size of vegetable Id in vegetable table?

Comment: whether id is unsigned? or it is binary?

Comment: no its just primary key with auto increment, (id of vegetable table)

Comment: The vegetable id of vegetable table which is a primary key is given as 4 . I mean the size

Comment: But u are using its size as 3 in the consumer table. make the sizes same and then try

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47186/discussion-between-user2492854-and-jailed-abroad)

Comment: no no  it worked  ,my silly mistake....  in the assignment of values .. I edited my code, it works now. anyway thank u very much for help me